# How to rotate a subview that was added to the window?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a `UITabBarController` subclass and there I have to following code:

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

Works great and there is a rotation when I flip my device. My problem is that in some parts of my app I want a layer to be on top of everything like a login screen etc' so I'm using this:

```
LoginView *loginView = [[LoginView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame delegate:self];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:loginView]; //<-- Won't rotate

//[self.view addSubview:loginView]; <-- will rotate but will not be on top of everything (tabbar etc')
```

In that case the login screen will not rotate. How can I have a subview that is a layer over everything and still force it to rotate like all the other views?

Comment: Read Apple HIG..you use modal presentation for that purpose...

Comment: Have you tried setting the bounds of the login view to the bounds of the current view? Bounds includes transforms such as rotation. The main window's orientation does not change.

Comment: @MarcusAdams I haven't. Mind sharing how to do so?